# python plotting arrays in nested loops

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, append

Plot of linear function:

[image]

```
import pylab as pylab
import numpy as np

xx = []
yy = [] 
zz = []

for x in np.arange(0, 12, 2): 
    for y in np.arange(0, 11, 1):

        z=x+y
        xx.append(x)
        yy.append(y)
        zz.append(z)

pylab.plot(yy, zz, color="blue")
pylab.xlabel('x or y')
pylab.ylabel('z')
pylab.show()
```

The above code is intended  to plot a series of parallel lines.  However, it also connects the lines in a zigzag pattern which is not desired.  How can i fix this problem.  I need the double loop (nested loop) but I don't want to plot the the connection between the parallel lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you are generating and plotting the data. By changing to `pylab.scatter` you can see that the shape of your data is correct but the way you are generating it is overcomplicated.

[image]

Below is a simplified example which produces the graph:

```
import pylab as pylab
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 11, 1)
y = np.arange(0, 11, 1)

for i in range (6):
    pylab.plot(x, y, color='blue')
    y = np.add(y,2)

pylab.xlabel('x or y')
pylab.ylabel('z')
pylab.show()
```

This produces the following graph:

[image]